# Add a value to a textbox in HTML using an external php form

Tags: php, html, textarea

I created an html document and a php document, both in separate files. I link the html with php by using the `<form action="myphp.php" method="get">`.

The problem is that once I process and evaluate values in php that I got from html, I want to display these values in the html page, inside this tag (text tag):

```
<input type="text" size="15" name="results" />
```

I don't know how to access this text box.

Comment: echo ????????????? `value="{$_GET['values']}"`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off keeping it simple and using a one page php script.

Just use one a php file like 'form.php', and post to itself (so you don't need an 'action=' property in your  tags.

Like below:

```
<?php 

    $results = '';
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['results']) {
        $results = $_REQUEST['results'];
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" size="15" name="results" value="<?= $results ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

$_REQUEST is just like writing $_GET or $_POST, just it accesses data from both if it exists.

There are different ways to approach the situation, like ajax requests (javascript) and templating systems (e.g. Smarty Templating). But at the end of the day you're best off keeping to PHP while you're learning.

Comment: while you don't need to specify the action, as get is the default, it is still a good idea to use it